# Sent post data by file_get_contents, post data readable by the client/browser?

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

if I use file_get_contents for sending post data to another .php with like the example given by the manual further down, could a visitor of this webpage have any possiblity to view/trace the post data that i send? Thanks

```
<?php

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);

?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Comment: The simple answer is no, because its happening at server-side that visitors don't have any access to it.

Comment: Welcome @murphy118. Do you mean, can they view the original file location? If that's the case, then no. PHP runs on the server and then delivers the output to the client after it processed. The client cannot see the server paths (unless the server outputs the raw php code because of an error).

Comment: Thank you two, yes I thought about that because of security reasons. In the other script some of these values trigger SQL statements, thats why.